# The concept of "almost everywhere" wrt to zero-dimensional measure $\mathcal H^0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

From my understanding, a function $u$ is defined $\mathcal H^0$-a.e. on an interval $I$ means that $u$ is only not "defined" on a set of points $A \subset I$ such that $\mathcal H^0(A)=0$

However, I think $\mathcal H^0(A)=0$ means that $A$ is empty, and hence implies that $u$ is defined everywhere in $I$. Because even if $A$ contains only a point, then $\mathcal H^0(A)=1>0$.

My question: can somebody confirm for me that "defined $\mathcal H^0$ a.e. is equivalent to defined everywhere" is correct? or am I making some trivial mistake?

---

PS: $\mathcal H^0$ means Housdroff measure in $0$ dimensions. Also, we may think it as a counting measure.

Comment: What measure is $\mathcal H^0$?

Comment: $x$ almost everywhere means that the set $\{y \mid \neg x(y)\}$ has measure zero. Since the only measure zero set for $\mathcal H^0$ is $\emptyset$, $x$ must be true everywhere if it is true almost everywhere wrt $\mathcal H^0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the zero-dimensional Hausdorff measure $\mathcal H^0$ is simply the *counting measure*, and the only null set for this measure is the empty set.

Example of usage: if $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a Borel set of zero length (meaning $\mathcal H^1(A)=0$), then for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the slice 
$$A_x = \{y\in \mathbb{R}: (x,y)\in A\}$$
has zero $\mathcal{H}^0$ measure. (This is an instance of a more general result.) In practical terms, this means the intersection of $A$ with almost every vertical line is empty.

Comment: I have a question here. Say $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ with $\mathcal H^1(A)<+\infty$. Then would it be possible to prove that for $\mathcal H^1$ a.e. $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $\mathcal H^0(A_x)<\infty$?

Comment: You mean: $\mathcal H^0(A_x)<0$, probably (for $\mathcal H^1$ it's trivial, a subset has smaller measure). Yes, this is also an instance of that more general result I alluded to: _coarea formula_, applied to a coordinate projection map.

Comment: Sir. Could you expand your comment about $\mathcal H^0(A_x)<+\infty?$ you mean coarea formula or it should be area formula? Thank you!